# Method access in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

How is it that Ruby allows a class access methods outside of the class implicitly?

Example:

```
class Candy
    def land
        homer
    end
end

def homer
    puts "Hello"
end

Candy.new.land #Outputs Hello
```

Comment: See http://www.sitepoint.com/rubys-top-self-object/ or https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/ for detailed explanations of Ruby's top-level object.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The definition of the "homer" method is adding the method to the Object class.  It is not defining a free function.

Class Candy implicitly inherits from Object, and so has access to the methods in Object.   When you call "homer" in the "land" method, the method resolution can't find a definition in the current class, goes to the super class, finds the method you have added to Object, and calls it.

Comment: See my clarification below... It is defined on the Kernel module, not the Object class.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to find out what happens

1. What classes/modules are searched to resolve methods used in Candy objects?

   p Candy.ancestors #=>  [Candy, Object, Kernel]
2. Does Candy have method called homer?

   p Candy.instance_methods(false).grep("homer") #=> []

   p Candy.private_instance_methods(false).grep("homer") #=> []
3. OK Candy does not have any method called 'homer'.
4. What's next in the lookup chain (see 1) => "Object"
5. Does Object have a method called "homer" ?
      p Object.instance_methods(false).grep("homer") #=> []

   p Object.private_instance_methods(false).grep("homer") #=> ["homer"]

*Candy has Object in its lookup chain which in turn has a private instance  method "homer" so method resolution succeeds*

The **def statement** always defines the method in the class of whatever **self** is at the point of definition

1. What is *self* just before homer is defined ?

   p self #=> main
     def homer
       puts "Hello"
     end
2. So what is its type ?

   p self.class #=> Object

Which is why *homer* ends up on *Object*

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Technically, the definition of the `homer` method is actually on the `Kernel` module which is mixed into `Object`, not on `Object` directly. So when `homer` is not a local variable or an instance method defined on `Candy`, the Ruby method inheritance chain is followed up through `Object` and then to the mixed-in `Kernel` module and then this code is run.</strike>

**Edit:** Sorry, I don't know why I thought this. It appears that the method really lives on `Object`. Not sure it makes too much of a difference in practice but I should have confirmed things before posting.

Comment: technically you're wrong, it's defined on `Object` not on `Kernel`, `method(:homer).owner => Object`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has no free-floating functions. Every method belongs to some object. Methods that you `def` at the top level are actually becoming instance methods of class `Object`. Because everything is an `Object` at some level, all objects have access to `Object`'s instance methods.